# Isomorphism and the Subspace of Annihilators

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a subspace of a vector space, $V$.  
$V'$ is the set of linear functionals on $V$, and $(V')' = V''$ is the set of linear functionals on $V'$. 
I already viewed the proof for the statement that $V$ is isomorphic to $V''$ ($V \cong V''$). 
The function $f:  V \rightarrow V''$ defined by $f(x) = z_x$ where $z_x(y) = y(x)$ for all $y \in V'$ is the isomorphism.

Now, let $M^0 = \{ y \in V' : \forall x \in M, \space y(x) = 0\}$. 
Parallelly, we have $(M^0)^0 = M^{00} = \{ z \in V'' : \forall y \in M^0, \space z(y) = 0\}$. 
$M$ is a subspace in $V$, $M^0$ a subspace in $V'$, $M^{00}$ in $V''$, but $V \neq V''$.  So, how can you say that $M = M^{00}$?  Even my text, Halmos's FDVS, admits that it is imprecise language (p. 25, 2nd Ed).

I made an educated guess.  If $V \cong V''$, and dim$M$ = dim$M^{00}$ as Halmos proved later (p. 27), then $M \cong M^{00}$.  So vectors in $M \subset V$ determine which $z \in V''$ is identically $0$.  However, what if the isomorphism $f:  V \rightarrow V''$ is not unique?  Then, how do I know that $M$ alone captures all the $z \in M^{00}$?

Please kindly examine the previous paragraph.  To be honest, I haven't entirely understood why $V \cong V'' \land$ dim$M$ = dim$M^{00} \rightarrow M \cong M^{00}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that for $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space, even though there are many isomorphisms $V \to V^{\prime\prime}$, this particular isomorphism $$f : V \to V^{\prime\prime}, \quad v \mapsto z_v := (\phi \mapsto \phi(v)),$$ is considered to be the canonical isomorphism $V \cong V^{\prime\prime}$ in the mathematical literature, and indeed can be shown to be natural in the sense of category theory. So, whenever you see $V$ and $V^{\prime\prime}$ identified, it is *always* via this particular isomorphism. In particular, then, the statement $M = M^{00}$ is really abuse of notation for the statement $f(M) = M^{00}$.

So, suppose you know that $f : V \to V^{\prime\prime}$ is an isomorphism, and that $\dim M = \dim M^{00}$. Observe that $f(M) \subseteq M^{00}$, for if $v \in M$, then for any $\phi \in M^0$, $f(v)(\phi) = \phi(v) = 0$, and hence $f(v) \in M^{00}$. So, $f(M)$ is a subspace of $M^{00}$ with the same dimension as $M^{00}$. Since everything in sight is finite-dimensional, what can you then conclude?

Comment: TY for clearing this up.  $f(M) = M^{00}$ makes sense now.